# Filter on filter multiple columns using dropdown in a table using angular 2

Tags: pipe, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I am displaying a JSON data in a table which has 3 columns and dropdown for each column.I have a written pipe to filter data using the select dropdown. I have 3 columns I have written 3 separate pipes and I am trying to filter 3 columns using a single pipe

Below is the code which I have written:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filterNames',
  pure: false
})
export class FilterNamesPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any, query1: any,query2:any,query3): string {
    if (!query1 || query2 || query3) return items;
    return items.filter(function(item){
      if(item.firstName.includes(query1) || item.lastname.includes(query2) || item.middleName(query3)){
        return true;
      }
      else {
        return false;
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Items variable have the JSON data, `query1`, `query2` `query3` are the values in 3 different dropDowns. When I filter columns with `query1` or `query2` or `query3`, filtering of data is working fine, but when I filter on top of another filter then the first applied filter data is changing.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do that with pipe. I think it's better to attach something like (change) event listener on your select dropdowns in a template, like this:

```
<select name="firstNameFilter" id="1" (change)="onFilter('firstName', $event.target.value)"></select>

<select name="lastnameFilter" id="2" (change)="onFilter('lastname', $event.target.value)"></select>

<select name="middleNameFilter" id="3" (change)="onFilter('middleName', $event.target.value)"></select>
```

And then create an onFilter method in your ts file, which will filter your JSON data:

```
onFilter(property: string, value: string) {
  // filter the data
}
```

Filtering itself could be done using [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method which will return a new array of objects.